# Android: Set ListView-Background

Tags: android, listview, user-interface

I've set the background in my xml via android:background to a bitmap drawable.

The problem is, that the background flickers and disapears when the user scrolls in the ListView. After stopping the background apears again. That's horrible - is there a work around?

I'm using a Android 2.2 phone. (Wildfire)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

reading [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html) website may give you a clear understanding as to why you would do this

Comment: Dang - I was already on the page today and after scanning it I didn't think it was valuable enough to read it properly.

Comment: the more you read from that website the better you will become!